# Generate reports in netbeans with windows 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, report, windows-8.1

I am trying to make a report using netbeans and my OS is Windows 8.1 ... I've tried the Japser reports but it's not updated for windows 8 and it switched to jaspersoft studio now.. And i've been googling and a lot says it only works in Eclipse. Is it true? And what other reports generator can I use? thank you

Comment: `I've tried the Japser reports but it's not updated for windows 8` - What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Assume you are talking about iReports here. have you tried what is mentioned here ([iReport 5.5.1 Doesn't Load](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/825724/ireport-551-doesnt-load))

And yes jasper studio is an eclipse based tool, so it cannot be used outside eclipse

Comment: I tried it, but when I was about to save the edited ireport.conf it says "access denied". And so I tried to copy what's inside that file and erased that, and made new ireport.conf and pasted it, it says "you cannot save in this location" :(

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really a beginner with this. Idk how to do this

Comment: You will need administrator privileges to edit this file. What you can do is which ever editor you are using to edit this file, right click and run it as an administrator and then open the ireport.conf file. Then you should be able to save it